# How do I check on which branch a label resides?

Tags: clearcase

How Can I check if a label has been applied on main branch or the project branch?

I have a label which we apply on all the elements in a VOB in main branch, but I just found out that the label is applied on certain elements in a project branch.
Therefore I now need to make checks to find if any other elements on the sub branch have this particular label.

Comment: I see you have a lot of other ClearCase question without any accepted answer (http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Please take the time to review them.

Comment: Will do that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I now need to make checks to find if any other elements on the sub branch have this particular label

A [cleartool find](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-14&lang=en) query shoould be enough:

```
cleartool find -all -version "lbtype(mylabel) && brtype(mybranch)" -print
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd make a slight change in case there were multiple project or developer branches:

cleartool find -all -version "lbtype(mylabel) && !brtype(main)" -print

This would print only the versions that have the label that AREN'T on /main.

Yes, I know it's a quibble...